# How to concatenate words hyphenated and split across two lines

Tags: r

I m working on multi-columns pdfs.
I have converted the multi columns into one column with the package tabulazer .
Here the result :

```
text <- "La voiture que conduit Annie suit, à tra-
vers neige et brouillard, la série de lacets
qui conduit de Corenc - non loin de
Grenoble - où les Schaerer demeurent
dans une maison faisant face à la chaîne
de Beldonne, à Mens - au sud de l'Isère,
en pleine Trièves - où René passa son
enfance. Entre deux tournants, la con-
ductrice apporte une précision que n'a
pas formulée son mari, et qui lui appa-
raît capitale : "
```

What I want :

```
"La voiture que conduit Annie suit, à travers neige et brouillard, la série de lacets
qui conduit de Corenc - non loin de Grenoble - où les Schaerer demeurent dans une maison faisant face à la chaîne de Beldonne, à Mens - au sud de l'Isère, en pleine Trièves - où René passa son enfance. Entre deux tournants, la conductrice apporte une précision que n'a pas formulée son mari, et qui lui apparaît capitale : "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solvable with some simple substitition. R reads your input as

```
> text
[1] "La voiture que conduit Annie suit, à tra-\nvers neige et brouillard, la série de lacets\nqui conduit de Corenc - non loin de\nGrenoble - où les Schaerer demeurent\ndans une maison faisant face à la chaîne\nde Beldonne, à Mens - au sud de l'Isère,\nen pleine Trièves - où René passa son\nenfance. Entre deux tournants, la con-\nductrice apporte une précision que n'a\npas formulée son mari, et qui lui appa-\nraît capitale : "
```

Let us first remove the `"-\n"` with

```
> text2 <- gsub("-\n","",text)
[1] "La voiture que conduit Annie suit, à travers neige et brouillard, la série de lacets\nqui conduit de Corenc - non loin de\nGrenoble - où les Schaerer demeurent\ndans une maison faisant face à la chaîne\nde Beldonne, à Mens - au sud de l'Isère,\nen pleine Trièves - où René passa son\nenfance. Entre deux tournants, la conductrice apporte une précision que n'a\npas formulée son mari, et qui lui apparaît capitale : "
```

And finally remove the remaining `\n` with

```
> gsub("\n"," ",text2)
[1] "La voiture que conduit Annie suit, à travers neige et brouillard, la série de lacets qui conduit de Corenc - non loin de Grenoble - où les Schaerer demeurent dans une maison faisant face à la chaîne de Beldonne, à Mens - au sud de l'Isère, en pleine Trièves - où René passa son enfance. Entre deux tournants, la conductrice apporte une précision que n'a pas formulée son mari, et qui lui apparaît capitale : "
```

Leaving us with

> La voiture que conduit Annie suit, à travers neige et brouillard, la
> série de lacets qui conduit de Corenc - non loin de Grenoble - où les
> Schaerer demeurent dans une maison faisant face à la chaîne de
> Beldonne, à Mens - au sud de l'Isère, en pleine Trièves - où René
> passa son enfance. Entre deux tournants, la conductrice apporte une
> précision que n'a pas formulée son mari, et qui lui apparaît capitale
> :

To summarise, perform the following replacements:

- `"-\n"` -> `""`
- `"\n"` -> `" "`

If you want this in one step, use the following command `gsub("\n"," ",(gsub("-\n","",text)))`